# ¿Cómo actualizo lo establecido en una Preference en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Soy nuevo con lo de preferencias y cuando el usuario da en guardar lo cual lo tengo en un switch quiero que me aparezca el nombre de manera automática y otra como pongo un botón en las preferencias, lo que pasa es que para que me muestre el nombre tengo que salir y volver a entrar, lo que quiero es que cuando salga de la preferencias me muestre el nombre.

Aquí el código de xml preferences:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Datos de Usuario">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="opcion1"
        android:title="Sonido"
        android:summary="Activa o desactiva el sonido" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="opcion2"
        android:title="Nombre de Usuario"
        android:summary="Identifica al usuario de la aplicación"
        android:dialogTitle="Introduce valor" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Datos de Paises">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="opcion3"
        android:title="Pais"
        android:summary="País del usuario"
        android:dialogTitle="Indicar Pais"
        android:entries="@array/pais"
        android:entryValues="@array/codigopais" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Guardar">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="swicth"
        android:title="Guradar"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Aquí el código de la clase principal donde muestra el nombre:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences pref =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);


        if (pref.getBoolean("swicth",true)){
            info.setText(pref.getString("opcion2",""));
        }else{
            info.setText("Null");
        }

        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 1: " + pref.getBoolean("opcion1", false));
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 2: " + pref.getString("opcion2", ""));
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 3: " + pref.getString("opcion3", ""));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Una solución usando el metodo `onResume()` de tu Activity y por medio de un método realizar la carga de los valores:

```
//Defines variable para obtener preferencias a nivel de clase.
SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       pref =
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

  // llamamos método cargaDatos();
cargaDatos();


    }


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // llamamos método cargaDatos();
     cargaDatos();
}


private void cargaDatos(){

        if (pref.getBoolean("swicth",true)){
            info.setText(pref.getString("opcion2",""));
        }else{
            info.setText("Null");
        }

        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 1: " + pref.getBoolean("opcion1", false));
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 2: " + pref.getString("opcion2", ""));
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 3: " + pref.getString("opcion3", ""));


}
```

De esta forma cuando regreses a tu Activity se cargaran los valores definidos en la preferencia.

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma sino me equivoco podría ser la siguiente:

- hacer que tu actividad de preferencias implemente el listener de cambio de preferencias `implements`SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
- Sobrescribir la función `onSharedPreferenceChanged`

```java
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged ( SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) 
{
    if("switch".equals(key)){
        if (pref.getBoolean("swicth",true)){
            info.setText(pref.getString("opcion2",""));
        }else{
            info.setText("Null");
        }
    }else if("opcion1".equals(key)){
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 1: " + pref.getBoolean("opcion1", false)); 
    } else if("opcion2".equals(key)){
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 2: " + pref.getString("opcion2", ""));
    } else if("opcion3".equals(key)){
        Log.i("NavigationDrawer", "Opción 3: " + pref.getString("opcion3", ""));
    }
}
```